# Is $10x^3+13x^2-67-15x$ a valid simplification of $5(2x^3+5x^2-8)-3(4x^2+5x+9)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I'm currently learning how to simplify algebraic expressions, and I saw this one example online which looked like this.

$$5(2x^3 + 5x^2 -8) -3(4x^2+5x+9)$$

And what I did was this, I used the distributive property followed by combining liked terms.
So after distributing I ended up with
$$10x^3 + 25x^2 - 40 -12x^2 -15x -27$$
And then I combined liked terms and ended up with.

$$10x^3 + 13x^2 -67 -15x$$

But the solution on the example was
$$10x^3 + 13x^2  -15x -67$$

Now, in my head it made sense to just do them in order so that $-67$ would come before $-15x$, but is there a rule that states that you should always write the value with the variable in it prior to the constant? Would my answer be a valid answer?

Comment: Yes, it is called the commutative property of addition. There is nothing *wrong* with your answer, but polynomials are typically written in an order - either the exponents increase or decrease from left to right.

Comment: Ah! That explains the confusion, thank you very much!

Comment: To further elaborate on @AmejiB.'s comment, $67$ is equivalent to $67\times x^0$ since $x^0 = 1$ and $67 \times 1 = 67$. Therefore, in the solution you see the exponents arranged in a decreasing order from $3$ to $0$.